# How can I load the data from a csv file, rather than being typed into my python program

Tags: python, csv

I would like to take these inputs loaded from a csv file. Not typed into the python code. What changes should I make? I created the csv file. I have problem importing the data in the python-code.

**The source code is from this link https://github.com/joelgrus/data-science-from-scratch/blob/master/code/decision_trees.py**

The inputs I would like to import from a csv file are the following:

```
inputs = [
        ({'level':'Senior','lang':'Java','tweets':'no','phd':'no'},   False),
        ({'level':'Senior','lang':'Java','tweets':'no','phd':'yes'},  False),
        ({'level':'Mid','lang':'Python','tweets':'no','phd':'no'},     True),
        ({'level':'Junior','lang':'Python','tweets':'no','phd':'no'},  True),
        ({'level':'Junior','lang':'R','tweets':'yes','phd':'no'},      True),
        ({'level':'Junior','lang':'R','tweets':'yes','phd':'yes'},    False),
        ({'level':'Mid','lang':'R','tweets':'yes','phd':'yes'},        True),
        ({'level':'Senior','lang':'Python','tweets':'no','phd':'no'}, False),
        ({'level':'Senior','lang':'R','tweets':'yes','phd':'no'},      True),
        ({'level':'Junior','lang':'Python','tweets':'yes','phd':'no'}, True),
        ({'level':'Senior','lang':'Python','tweets':'yes','phd':'yes'},True),
        ({'level':'Mid','lang':'Python','tweets':'no','phd':'yes'},    True),
        ({'level':'Mid','lang':'Java','tweets':'yes','phd':'no'},      True),
        ({'level':'Junior','lang':'Python','tweets':'no','phd':'yes'},False)
    ]
```

I imported them finally by hand. (I created a csv, writing the data and then i import them to the script).
My aim was to export the csv file and then import automatically the values to the script.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I imported them finally by hand. (I created a csv, writing the data and then i import them to the script). My aim was to export the csv file and then import automatically the values to the script.

Comment: The answer is well defined and a sloppy Google query away. Try solving it yourself. If you still have not the slightest idea of how to do it afterwards, come back.

Answer (score 0):

If your csv file is formatted as

```
level,lang,tweets,phd
Senior,Java,no,no
................
```

You can use

```
csvfile=open('your_csv_file.csv',encoding="utf8")
csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
for record in csvreader:
    #do watever you want
```